# Vue: multi-page SSR + Hydrate with partial loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, server-side-rendering

I want to write an application using NestJS. But coming from PHP, I am very much used to the SSR approach of rendering views for the client. Now, by using JavaScript, I could technically ask the server to not completely navigate a page, but just load the `<body>` element of the sent output, and then embed that into - and overwriting - the current view. By what I can tell, initially, this would work as I would just `app.$mount(...)` on the initially sent HTML and have Vue hydrate off that.

But what if I want to implement this across multiple pages?

The idea is, that by using SSR, I get to keep basically all SEO related features and can reduce the initially loaded JavaScript by taking advantage of WebPack's lazy-loading feature. But when a user navigates from page A (initially loaded) to page B (subsequent load), I would like to just replace/update the current content and then load the bundle apropriate to that page and hydrate.

Is that possible, and if, how?

So far, I know I would have to unload the currently used bundle to remove all references to events and objects from memory, and then load the new bundle in, which I can then use to hydrate the received view. And this does not take into account that a menu bar might not need to be treated separately, since it will only have to have the current location updated with a `.current` class appended to the relevant menu item. I might be wrong here, but that is why I ask :)